# Is it possible to create a phone calling method in service in android studio?

Tags: android

I am making an app which diverts the call when my battery reaches the critical level (say 1%), as the sim in my country does not facilitate the service of divert when switch off.

For this I need to create a service that regularly checks battery level until it reaches 1%.

And I did that now I must make a call to **21*number# in my service so as to send network service command to divert the call but in background service.

I want to make this method work

```
 public void divertCalls(){
    spdf1= getSharedPreferences("divertInfo",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    numberDivert = spdf1.getString("phone_details","");
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0377778888"));
    startActivity(callIntent);


}
```

Comment: Please explain what exactly isn't working as expected, and what you expect from that piece of code. You might also want to read ["How to Ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Well! I want to implement this method in a service
 public void divertCalls()
 { 
spdf1 = getSharedPreferences("divertInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
numberDivert = spdf1.getString("phone_details", "");
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL); intent.setData(Uri.parse("*21"+numberDivert+"#")); intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND); startActivity(intent); 
} 
it says calls requires permission and all